# Adding text to panels in lattice barchart

Tags: r, panel, label, bar-chart, lattice

I try to add labels to bars in a lattice barchart with multiple panels. I end up with way too many labels (every label is in every panel).

Here is my code:

```
library(lattice)
data(iris)

barchart(seq(1,50) ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, data = iris, stack = TRUE,
         panel=function(x, y, ...) {
               panel.barchart(x, y, ...);
               ltext(x=iris$Petal.Width/2, y=y, labels=iris$Petal.Width, cex = 0.5);
               ltext(x=iris$Petal.Width + iris$Petal.Length/2, y=y, labels=iris$Petal.Width, cex = 0.5);
         }
)
```

How would I do this right?

**Bonus question:**
Beside it does not work as expected, I think my code is not too efficient (especially `seq(1,50)` and `Petal.Width + Petal.Length`). Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The underlying question here is how to put labels on a stacked bar chart using `lattice`. This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3220702/602276

Comment: hm, maybe I don't get it right but my problem is not "how to put labels on a stacked bar chart" but "how to make the labels match the panel they belong to".
Is this question really answered in the thread you linked?

Comment: Yes, it really is the same problem.  To prove this, I have provided an answer below using a much simplified version of the panel function (but the core idea is the same - calculate the cumulative sum of `x` for each `y`).  HTH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The underlying question here is how to add labels to a stacked barchart in `lattice`.  The answer is provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3220702/602276), but since the linked answer doesn't have multiple panels, I recreate a simpler answer using base R here:

You have to modify the panel function as follows:

- Calculate the cumulative sum of x values for each y value
- This is a classic split, apply, combine problem.  You can use `plyr` for this (as in the linked answer), or, as I illustrate, `split` and `do.call`:

`xx <- do.call(c, unname(lapply(split(x, y), function(t)cumsum(t)-t/2)))`

The code:

```
barchart( 1:10 ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, 
          data = iris[c(1:10, 51:60, 101:110), ], 
          stack = TRUE,
          panel=function(x, y, ...) {
            panel.barchart(x, y, ...)
            xx <- do.call(c, unname(lapply(split(x, y), function(t)cumsum(t)-t/2)))
            ltext(xx, y=y, labels=x)
         }
)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! but here the label of Petal.Length is not in the middle of the Petal.Length bar but in the middle of the whole bar.

Comment: OK, I copied the solution in the linked answer incorrectly.  It should now be fixed.

Comment: I edited your solution for another working option but yours is even better :)