# How to set up labels of stacked bar charts created with lattice in R?

Tags: r, lattice

Some time ago I [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28489321/1354580) to put labels as percentages in stacked bar charts created with the `likert` function from the `HH` package, that uses `lattice`. My data was answers to a Likert-type scale with an **even number of levels** and the 
code works as I expected.

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
|   | Strongly Disagree | Moderate Disagree | Slightly Disagree | Slightly Agree | Moderate Agree | Strongly Agree | Group              |
+===+===================+===================+===================+================+================+================+====================+
| 1 | 2.00              | 1.00              | 3.00              | 1.00           | 4.00           | 9.00           | Experimental group |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
| 2 | 1.00              | 2.00              | 1.00              | 5.00           | 5.00           | 6.00           | Control group      |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+----------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

[image]
When I tried to use my code with an **odd number of levels** I noticed an strange issue, the percentages that represents the middle answer are divided into two equal parts, that was not an expected behavior. In the middle section we must see the sum of that two percentages. How to solve this issue?

```
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
|   | Strongly Disagree | Moderate Disagree | Neither Agree nor Disagree | Moderate Agree | Strongly Agree | Group              |
+===+===================+===================+============================+================+================+====================+
| 1 | 0.00              | 0.00              | 9.00                       | 10.00          | 1.00           | Experimental Group |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
| 2 | 1.00              | 5.00              | 10.00                      | 4.00           | 0.00           | Control Group      |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------------------+
```

[image]

The data with an **even** number of levels:

```
data.freq <- structure(list(`Strongly Disagree` = c(2L, 1L), `Moderate Disagree` = 1:2, `Slightly Disagree` = c(3L, 1L), `Slightly Agree` = c(1L, 5L), `Moderate Agree` = 4:5, `Strongly Agree` = c(9L, 6L), Group = c("Experimental group", "Control group")), .Names = c("Strongly Disagree", "Moderate Disagree", "Slightly Disagree", "Slightly Agree", "Moderate Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Group"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

The data with an **odd** number of levels:

```
data.freq <- structure(list(`Strongly Disagree` = 0:1, `Moderate Disagree` = c(0L, 5L), `Neither Agree nor Disagree.` = 9:10, `Moderate Agree` = c(10L, 4L), `Strongly Agree` = c(1L, 0L), Group = c("Experimental Group", "Control Group")), .Names = c("Strongly Disagree", "Moderate Disagree", "Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Moderate Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Group"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")
```

The code:

```
library(HH)
ppi <- 150
jpeg("ssb_%02d.jpg", width=7*ppi, height=4*ppi, res=ppi)
scales.lab <- seq(-100, 100, by = 20)

plot_obj <- likert(Group ~ . | Group, data = data.freq, as.percent = TRUE, positive.order = TRUE,
    main="", xlab="",
    ylab="", ylab.right = list("Subjects per group", cex=1.1),
    scales = list(y = list(relation = "free", labels=""), cex=1.1, 
        x = list(at=scales.lab, labels=paste(abs(scales.lab), "%", sep = "")), cex = 0.8),
    layout = c(1, 2), auto.key=list(space="bottom", columns=3, cex.title=1.1, title="Levels", cex=1.1, size = 1, between.columns=0.5))

plot_obj <- plot_obj +
    layer({
        id = which(x > 0)
        xx = 0.5 * (cumsum(x[id]) + cumsum(c(0, x[id][-length(id)])))
        keep = x[id] >= 5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[id][keep], labels = paste(x[id][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)
        id = which(x < 0)
        xx = 0.5 * (cumsum(x[id]) + cumsum(c(0, x[id][-length(id)])))
        keep = x[id] <= -5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[id][keep], labels = paste(-x[id][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)
    })

print(plot_obj)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
## even
data.freq.even <- structure(list(`Strongly Disagree` = c(2L, 1L),
`Moderate Disagree` = 1:2, `Slightly Disagree` = c(3L, 1L),
`Slightly Agree` = c(1L, 5L), `Moderate Agree` = 4:5, `Strongly Agree`
= c(9L, 6L), Group = c("Experimental group", "Control group")), .Names
= c("Strongly Disagree", "Moderate Disagree", "Slightly Disagree",
"Slightly Agree", "Moderate Agree", "Strongly Agree", "Group"),
row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")

legend.labels.even <- c("Strongly\nDisagree", "Moderate\nDisagree", "Slightly\nDisagree",
"Slightly\nAgree", "Moderate\nAgree", "Strongly\nAgree")

## odd
data.freq.odd <- structure(list(`Strongly Disagree` = 0:1,
`Moderate Disagree` = c(0L, 5L), `Neither Agree nor Disagree.` = 9:10,
`Moderate Agree` = c(10L, 4L), `Strongly Agree` = c(1L, 0L), Group =
c("Experimental Group", "Control Group")), .Names =
c("Strongly Disagree", "Moderate Disagree",
"Neither Agree nor Disagree", "Moderate Agree", "Strongly Agree",
"Group"), row.names = c("1", "2"), class = "data.frame")

legend.labels.odd <- c("Strongly\nDisagree", "Moderate\nDisagree",
"Neither Agree\nnor Disagree", "Moderate\nAgree", "Strongly\nAgree")

library(HH)

scales.lab <- seq(-100, 100, by = 20)

MalaiPlot <- function(data.freq, legend.labels, legend.columns,
                      data.columns=c(left=3, middle=1, right=3), ## Assumption: 7 columns with three left, one middle, and three right.
                      ...) {

  plot_obj <- likert(Group ~ . | Group, data = data.freq, as.percent = TRUE, positive.order = TRUE,
                     main="", xlab="",
                     ylab="", ylab.right = list("Subjects per group", cex=1.1),
                     scales = list(y = list(relation = "free", labels=""), cex=1.1,
                       x = list(at=scales.lab, labels=paste(abs(scales.lab), "%", sep = "")), cex = 0.8),
                     layout = c(1, 2),
                     auto.key=list(
                       space="bottom", columns=3, cex.title=1.1,
                       title="Levels", cex=1.1, size = 1, between.columns=0.5),
                     data.columns=data.columns,
                     ...)

  plot_obj <- plot_obj +
    layer({
      if (data.columns["middle"] == 0) { ## even

        left <- seq(from=1, length=data.columns["left"])
        middle <- integer(0)
        right <- seq(from=data.columns["left"]+1, length=data.columns["right"])

        xx <- 0.5 * (cumsum(x[right]) + cumsum(c(0, x[right][-length(right)])))
        keep <- x[right] >= 5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[right][keep], labels = paste(x[right][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)

        xx = 0.5 * (cumsum(x[left]) + cumsum(c(0, x[left][-length(left)])))
        keep = x[left] <= -5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[left][keep], labels = paste(-x[left][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)
      } else { ## odd

        left <- seq(from=2, length=data.columns["left"])
        middle <- c(1, data.columns["left"]+2)
        right <- seq(data.columns["left"]+3, length=data.columns["right"])

        xx <- (0.5 * (cumsum(x[c(middle[2], right)]) + cumsum(c(0, x[c(middle[2], right[-length(right)])]))))[-1]
        keep <- x[right] >= 5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[right][keep], labels = paste(x[right][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)

        xx <- 0
        keep <- sum(abs(x)[middle]) >= 5
        panel.text(xx[keep], y[middle][keep], labels = paste(sum(abs(x)[middle])[keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)


       xx <- (0.5 * (cumsum(abs(x)[c(middle[1], left)]) + cumsum(c(0, abs(x)[c(middle[1], left[-length(left)])]))))[-1]
        keep = x[left] <= -5
        panel.text(-xx[keep], y[left][keep], labels = paste(-x[left][keep], "%", sep = ""), cex = 0.8, srt = 45)
      }
    }, data=list(data.columns=data.columns))

  if (!missing(legend.labels))
    plot_obj$legend$bottom$args$text <- legend.labels
  if (!missing(legend.columns))
    plot_obj$legend$bottom$args$columns <- legend.columns

plot_obj
}

MalaiPlot(data.freq.odd, legend.labels=legend.labels.odd, legend.columns=5, data.columns=c(left=2, middle=1, right=2))

MalaiPlot(data.freq.even, legend.labels=legend.labels.even, legend.columns=6, data.columns=c(left=3, middle=0, right=3))
```